# Closing TCP ports in Windows firewall

Tags: delphi, tcp, port, firewall

I will try to close several ports using Delphi. that is, I want to close ports other than 80 and 443.
The program should add a rule to the firewall that restricts incoming connections through ports other than 80 and 443.
I found this way. But sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

```
procedure AddFirewallPortRule(const ACaption: string; APort: string; AIncoming: boolean);
var
  Profile: Integer;
  Policy2: OleVariant;
  RObject: OleVariant;
  NewRule: OleVariant;
begin

  Profile := NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE OR NET_FW_PROFILE2_PUBLIC OR NET_FW_PROFILE2_DOMAIN;
  Policy2 := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.FwPolicy2');
  RObject := Policy2.Rules;
  NewRule := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.FWRule');

  NewRule.Name        := ACaption;
  NewRule.Description := ACaption;

  NewRule.Protocol := NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP;
  NewRule.LocalPorts:=APort;

  NewRule.Enabled := True;
  NewRule.Grouping := 'My Interface Group';
  NewRule.Profiles := Profile;

  NewRule.Action := NET_FW_ACTION_BLOCK;

  if AIncoming then
    NewRule.Direction:=NET_FW_RULE_DIR_IN
  else
    NewRule.Direction:=NET_FW_RULE_DIR_OUT;

  RemoveExceptFromFirewall(ACaption);
  RObject.Add(NewRule);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);

begin

  AddFirewallPortRule('My_rule', '1-79,81-442,444-65535', True);

end;
```

Comment: And, your question is ... what, exactly? Why it doesn't work sometimes? What happens exactly when it doesn't work? Do you get an error? If so, what is it, and on which line? Is your app running with admin rights? Is the Windows Firewall installed when it fails? Not everyone uses Windows Firewall, they are other firewalls in the world.

Comment: Yes, app is running with admin rights and the Windows Firewall installed. 
On one computer it adds rules, and on the other it says "Access is denied" (run with administrator rights)

Comment: "*it says Access Denied*" - on which line?

Comment: Thanks you. To answer your question, I found the cause of the error. The error found before this function (AddFirewallPortRule ()).

Comment: I am using WebBrowser component. But this does not work correctly with the JS library. Can I install chrome component to delphi 10.4 and where can I find it?